# ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to add the attribute key to all users in ldap.

```
add: keyPair
keyPair: 0000000000
```

But it gives me:

```
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
        additional info: keyPair: attribute type undefined
```

How can I add the attribute keyPair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using an LDIF file to modify the "keyPair" attribute, would have to build something similar to eg. modifyexample.ldif:

`dn: uid=uidexample,ou=examples,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: person
keyPair: 0000000000`

and then run following command to execute the modification:

`ldapmodify -f modifyexample.ldif`

Comment: is it not possible to type it in the terminal?

Comment: If you execute ldapmodify as follows you should be able to interactively enter the contents of the ldif file listed above: `ldapmodify -a -D bindDN -w password`